# ASP.NET pie chart interactivity

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I am having some problem when trying to add interactivity in ASP.NET charts. I want to add the click function in pie chart series. The code is working fine but I am **not sure how to add click function**.

```
 protected void populateCategoryPieChart()
    {
        try
        {
            Chart2.Visible = true;
            Chart2.Titles.Clear();
            string query = string.Format("//sensitive data", Convert.ToInt64(sessionDdl.SelectedValue));
            DataTable dt = getData(query);

            int[] c = new int[dt.Rows.Count];
            string[] x = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
            int[] y = new int[dt.Rows.Count];


            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                c[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][0]);
                x[i] = obj.getCategoryByID(Convert.ToInt64(dt.Rows[i][0])).Name;
                y[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][1]);
            }

            populateCategoryList(c);

            Chart2.Series["Category"].Points.DataBindXY(x, y);
            Chart2.Series["Category"].Label = "#VALX";
            Chart2.Series["Category"].LabelForeColor = Color.Black;
            Chart2.Series["Category"]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside";

            Title title = new Title("Most Viewed Category", Docking.Top, new Font("Verdana", 13), Color.Black);
            Chart2.Titles.Add(title);

            Chart2.Legends.Add("Legend1");
            Chart2.Legends[0].Enabled = true;
            Chart2.Legends[0].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
            Chart2.Legends[0].Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            Chart2.Series["Category"].LegendText = "#VALX (#PERCENT)";
            Chart2.DataManipulator.Sort(PointSortOrder.Descending, Chart2.Series["Category"]);



            Chart2.Series["Category"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
            Chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea2"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
            Chart2.Legends[0].Enabled = true;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I have followed the example shown in the site [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456772.aspx) but it is not working for me and there was no error message.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to check out this post to see if it is what you are looking for:  [How to create a mouse click event for an item (point) from a Pie chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385676/how-to-create-a-mouse-click-event-for-an-item-point-from-a-pie-chart)